# jQuery animation and background images not showing in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-9, browser-support

I'm having a strange issue with IE9 where if I have multiple `<div>` elements on the page, where only 1 is visible at a time and then others are shown as a result of JavaScript actions on the page.

The issue I am having is that if an element is hidden (seems to only happen after being hidden for a certain amount of time), when I go to show the elements w/ jQuery `$('.className').fadeIn(500);` for example, the background image properties of the elements inside that DIV that is being shown are lost.

They are still there when inspecting the HTML w/ IE Developer Tools, but the background image seems to not be recognized for whatever reason. In the developer tools, I can click to edit the background image path, and simply hitting enter (not actually changing the path) makes the background appear.

Is there something with IE that makes it ignore elements if not displayed on the page for a certain amount of time? Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is very strange as this was never an issue for me in any other browser or any other version of IE.

Comment: Paragraphs are your friend :) I added them into your question to make it easier to read. Also, I fixed your code formatting so it wasn't being hidden. Welcome to StackOverflow! :)

Comment: Consider editing your question to include the specific HTML and CSS related to the problem so that visitors to your question can see the full picture and possibly help. Good luck!